# Multiple CPU not showing in task manager

Tags: windows, cpu, multi-core

I have an i7 intel core. Normally it shows 8 cpu's in my task manager, however for some strange reason it does not anymore. I can't recall changing anything. I noticed this problem when I wanted to run parallel matlab code locally on 8 cpu's. It only allowed a max of 1.

However if I go to task manager I can see my 8 different processors.
Also when I go to msconfig to boot.ini numproc says 1.

Anyone know what might cause this or how I can fix this?

Thx

*Edit*: It's windows XP 64bit btw

Comment: which version of windows?

Comment: You write: Normally it shows 8 cpu's in my task manager, however for some strange reason it does not anymore. And later: However if I go to task manager I can see my 8 different processors. I am confused: Can you see those 8 CPUs in the task manager, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. Click the **Start** button.
2. Type: **msconfig**
3. Open it and go to the second tab called **Boot**.
4. By clicking "Advanced Options..." you can change the "Number of processors",
   as shown with black arrows in the image above. It is best to just disable it so it auto-detects.

Comment: disabling it did the job, thx!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's Windows 7/Vista,
Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).

Click on advanced settings, and and uncheck "Limit Windows to x CPUs"

It should be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the bios.  In mine there is something like a MultiCore Yes/No setting.